# Node and Angular with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm new to Node, Angular and TypeScript all together, and I'm having a hard time getting a **single root project** to work off of TypeScript, have a Node back-end and an Angular 4 front-end framework.

That is, I'd like to use TypeScript to build all my Node models, routers, services - as well as all my Angular classes, components, services, etc.

Can anyone here provide an example or reference?

Comment: You could use .NET Core to host your SPA. The Angular template also supports server side rendering by utilizing an embedded Node server: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

Comment: I'm not interested in using .NET Core or any variation thereof..  Just Node for now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah like above. make sure you have node and npm installed, then go to https://cli.angular.io and follow the instructions in the command line

Comment: I've run the Angular CLI.. I can generate a running app with no problems.. what I don't seem to be able to do with the CLI is also create all my NodeJS back-end code run in TypeScript under the same project.. 

The CLI bundles everything into a dist.. but I don't see any of my Node views, routers, configs, models, etc..

Comment: @EyalZinder are you using "ng serve" on the command line and displaying localhost:4200 in your browser?

Comment: Trouty, 

I can run 'ng serve' just fine..  but I'm trying to incorporate a node back-end to the same project..  I'm trying to build my Node routes, data access services, models, etc..  then I'd like to run my 'Server.js' file (sort-of-speak) and launch the entire site as one.

Comment: In other words, I'm trying to avoid creating one project for my back-end/web/api, and one for my angular front-end

Answer (score 1):

try installing angular cli  it will setup every thing for you ,then you just have to run .